# How to change a variable 's last bit

Tags: bash

I want to change the IP's last bit.

```
IP=10.10.10.10  
echo $ip |cut -d"." -f1-3
```

Will display "`10.10.10`"
I want to include "`.0`"

Comment: Changing the last *bit* would be changing it to `.11` (ORing or XORing a `1`)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should have mentioned last value I guess.

Comment: @RajGowda The standard term for the parts of an IPv4 address is "[octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)#Use_in_internet_protocol_addresses)" (because it consists of 8 bits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ ip=10.10.10.10
$ echo "${ip%.*}.0"
10.10.10.0
```

1. `${ip%.*}` removes the last dot and the numbers after it.
2. `.0` adds `.0` to the end of the string.
3. This approach uses only shell making it faster than methods which require a pipeline.
4. It is best practice to use lower or mixed case for your variables.  The system uses all upper-dase variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

Comment: @RajGowda Please tick the green check beside the answer to let future visitors know this answer worked for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

XOR by 1 (Bash 4 for the Parameter Expansion):

```
ipv4_address="${ipv4_address%.*}.$(( ${ipv4_address##*.} ^ 1 ))"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in bash:

```
ip="10.10.10.10"
x=`echo $ip|cut -d "." -f1-3`
echo "$x.0"
```

Comment: This is both buggy and inefficient compared to John1024's answer. Re: "buggy", see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo); if you had `IFS=.`, for example, the `echo $ip` would be changing all the `.`s to spaces. Re: "inefficient", keep in mind that all command substitutions and pipelines require `fork()`ing off subprocesses, and then running `cut` requires `exec`ing a completely different executable into the memory space.